# TypeError: Column is not iterable while trying to typecast

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, typeerror, apache-spark-mllib

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    df2=trainingDF
    numericCols = [c for c in trainingDF.columns if c not in {names[i]}]
    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=numericCols, outputCol="features") 
    df = assembler.transform(df2)
    df=df.withColumnRenamed(names[i],"label")
    lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
    lrModel = lr.fit(df)
    evaluator = RegressionEvaluator()
    evaluator.setPredictionCol(names[i])
    evaluator.evaluate(df2[names[i]].cast(DoubleType()))
    rsq=evaluator.evaluate(df, {evaluator.metricName: "r2"})
    vif = round(1 / (1 - rsq), 2)
    print(vif)
```

I am getting an error on the following line. I want to pass all the columns of `df2` as double values and typecast them to double.

```py
evaluator.evaluate(df2[names[i]].cast(DoubleType()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator.evaluate), the method `evaluate` takes a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` object as the first parameter, but you have provided a column (`df2[names[i]].cast(DoubleType())` is of Column data type, not DataFrame).

> **`evaluate`(*dataset: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame, params: Optional[ParamMap] = None*) → float**
>
> Evaluates the output with optional parameters.
>
> *New in version 1.4.0*.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **dataset : *pyspark.sql.DataFrame***
>   a dataset that contains labels/observations and predictions
> - **params : *dict, optional***
>   an optional param map that overrides embedded params
>
> **Returns:**
>
> - **float**
>   metric